# How to get Visual Studio Code to stop looking for matching angle brackets on a bitshift operator?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

Trying the below code as an example:

```
template <typename T, uint32_t exp2>
class MyClass : private std::array<T, (1U << exp2)>
{
    public:
    private:
}

typedef uint32_t TWord;
```

VSCode seems to be looking for two right angle brackets to match the left bitshift operator. Because it can't find it, syntax highlighting is broken from that point on (see `public`, `private`, and `typedef`).

If I add two (illegal) right angle brackets to "fix" it, the syntax will highlight properly. See the differences below.

Broken:

[image]

"Fixed":

[image]

I've tried looking for extensions and modifying the `language-configuration.json` file for C++, but I've not been finding too much success. Nor am I finding too many recent hits on angle bracket syntax highlighting recently.

I've also tried looking into customizing the C++ grammar, but I haven't found a good place to change that.

Is there a way to fix this formatting issue? Or am I making a mistake in syntax?

Comment: what do you see when you use the `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes`?

Comment: Visual Studio Code is an IDE, not a compiler. Update your toolchain, if you need features from newer standards.

Comment: Replace `1U << ep2` with a call to a constexpr function. Or just replace `<<` with a macro.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ The bitshift operators have been there since the first version of C++, which even predates the first release of Visual Studio Code. It is not some fancy thing from a newer standard.

Comment: Hi, sorry, I'm new to Stack Overflow so I didn't realize comments didn't count as answers.

@starball I'm assuming you're talking about the left shift operator. Mousing over it, it's called a `punctuation.section.angle-brackets.begin.template.call.cpp`, so it's not recognizing it as its own operator.

Additionally, I see this behavior both in a VSCode with no extensions and one with just the C/C++ Extension pack.

@n.m.couldbeanAI Mmm, yeah, I'll work around it like that for now, I guess. Thank you!

Comment: It kind of shows that VSCode is not really production-ready for C++ programming yet.

Comment: @Sebastian nit: VS Code's job/goal is not to be production ready for every language under the sun. VS Code's job/goal is to be extensible for people to write language support extensions.

Comment: According to this https://github.com/jeff-hykin/better-cpp-syntax before-after comparison, the bitwise shift operators should already work without installing an extension.